# Scala: Sequential processing of file data

Tags: scala, future, sequential

I have a csv file from which i read data and populate my database. I am using scala to do this. Instead of firing db inserts in a paralleled way I want to execute the insert in sequential manner(i.e. one after another). I am not willing to use Await in a for loop. Any other approach apart from using await?

P.S: I have read the 1000 entries from csv to a list and looping on the list to create db inserts

Comment: Do you have an async method to insert into database? If not so, why don't you execute insert statements one by one in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some kind of `save(entity: T): Future[_]` method for your database, you can just fold your futures with flatMap (or for comprehension):

```
def saveAll(entities: List[T]): Future[Unit] 
  entities.foldLeft(Future.successful(())){
    case (f, entity) => for {
        _ <- f
        _ <- save(entity)
      } yield ()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is recursive function.  Less concise than `foldLeft`, but more readable to some.  Just one more option for your consideration (assume `save(entity: T): Future[R]`:

```
def saveAll(entities: List[T]): Future[List[R]] = {
  entities.headOption match {
    case Some(entity) => 
      for {
        head <- save(entity)
        tail <- saveAll(entities.tail)
      } yield {
        head :: tail
      }
    case None =>
      Future.successful(Nil)
  }
}
```

Yet another option, if your `save` method allows you to supply your own `ExecutionContext` i.e. `save(entity: T)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[R]`, is just fire the `Future`s concurrently but use a single thread execution context:

```
def saveAll(entities: List[T]): Future[List[R]] = {
  implicit ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutionService(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)
  Future.sequence(entities.map(save))
}
```

Comment: The single-thread-executor needs to be shut down. and I don't recommend creating threads like that, require an EC from the caller instead.